# Role of selectivity in index scan/seek

Tags: sql, indexing, query-optimization

I have been reading in many SQL books and articles that selectivity is an important factor in creating index. If a column has low selectivity, an index seek does more harm that good. But none of the articles explain why. Can anybody explain why it is so, or provide a link to a relevant article?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From SimpleTalk article by Robert Sheldon: [14 SQL Server Indexing Questions You Were Too Shy To Ask](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/14-sql-server-indexing-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)

> The ratio of unique values within a key column is referred to as index
>   selectivity. The more unique the values, the higher the selectivity,
>   which means that a unique index has the highest possible selectivity.
>   The query engine loves highly selective key columns, especially if
>   those columns are referenced in the WHERE clause of your frequently
>   run queries. The higher the selectivity, the faster the query engine
>   can reduce the size of the result set. The flipside, of course, is
>   that a column with relatively few unique values is seldom a good
>   candidate to be indexed.

Also check these articles:

- Check [this post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/24/sql-server-index-seek-vs-index-scan-diffefence-and-usage-a-simple-note/) by Pinal Dave
- [this other](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Index_Selectivity_and_Column_Order) on SQL Serverpedia
- [This forum post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1025396-338-1.aspx#bm1025751) on SqlServerCentral can help you too.
- [This article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Indexing/68636/) on SqlServerCentral also

From the SqlServerCentral article:

> In general, a nonclustered index should be selective. That is, the
>   values in the column should be fairly unique and queries that filter
>   on it should return small portions of the table.
>
> The reason for this is that key/RID lookups are expensive operations
>   and if a nonclustered index is to be used to evaluate a query it needs
>   to be covering or sufficiently selective that the costs of the lookups
>   aren’t deemed to be too high.
>
> If SQL considers the index (or the subset of the index keys that the
>   query would be seeking  on) insufficiently selective then it is very
>   likely that the index will be ignored and the query executed as a
>   clustered index (table) scan.
>
> It is important to note that this does not just apply to the leading
>   column. There are scenarios where a very unselective column can be
>   used as the leading column, with the other columns in the index making
>   it selective enough to be used.

Comment: You are welcome, be sure to test before running into production to avoid downtimes and therefore angry faces from users ;)

Answer (score 4):

I try to write a very simple explanation (based on my current knowledge of Sql Server):

If an index has low selectivity it means that for the same value a bigger percentage of the total rows are found. (like 200 from the 500 rows has the same value on your index based)

Usually if the index does not contain all the column information what you need, then it is using a pointer, where to find the row physically which is connected to that "entry" on the index. Then in a secpnd step the engine has to read out that row.

So as you see a search like this using two step. And here comes the selectivity:

More results you get becuse of the low selectivity more double work the engine has to do. So there are some cases because of this fact where even a table scan is more efficient then an index seek with very low selectivity.

Comment: But the number of results is more for table scan also. At least in case of index seek, the jump to the portion of the data block containing the similar records is faster.

Comment: But by table scan you are reading obe record once, not kind of twice. And you have to calculate the "headmove" time in the not ssd harddrives which is the most cost in the whole process.