# Which DB and what Indexes best suit for the case?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, sqlite, indexing

I need to create a DB which will store trades data for different exchanges.
The table columns are 'exchange name', 'timestamp' and 'data' (JSON string).
The only query I would need is 'get data for one or many exchanges with timestamp in defined range.

I don't think that amount of data will ever by more than 1GB and I'll keep DB locally on my laptop.

What would be best choice (in terms of speed) DB option: MySQL, PostgreSQL or SQLite?
What indexes should I create?

Comment: For 1gb talking about speed at first place is unnecessary. All choices will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

With 1 GB, there will be no noticeable speed difference. But with a self-contained laptop application, you do not need a client/server systen, so you should probably use an embedded database with less administration overhead.

You should create an index on the lookup column that has the highest [selectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155853/role-of-selectivity-in-index-scan-seek) in your queries, i.e., on the timestamp column. If there are enough different exchanges, it might make sense to include the exchange column in that index.

Comment: Thanks. But if there are few exchanges (up to 5). Doesn't it make sense to include this column in index anyway as all queries will have exchange in where clause?

Comment: That depends. Measure it.

Answer (score 0):

Use any RDBMS.

Use `IN`, not `OR`.

Have

```
INDEX(timestamp),
INDEX(exchange, timestamp)
```